# How can i display on the game window a variable float values in real time as text for testing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When running the game i want to display in real time some stats and info.
For now i want to display the landingSpeed variable value on the game window.
In the left top corner.

But it's not showing anything. I want to display it in the top left corner and to be able to set the text font size in the script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MakeObjectFly : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float AmbientSpeed = 100.0f;
    public float RotationSpeed = 200.0f;
    public float flightSpeed = 5.0f;
    public float landingSpeed = 100.0f;
    public bool isGrounded = true;

    Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text displaylandingspeed;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
        float roll = 0;
        float pitch = 0;
        float yaw = 0;
        roll = Input.GetAxis ("Roll") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        pitch = Input.GetAxis ("Pitch") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        yaw = Input.GetAxis ("Yaw") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (-pitch, yaw, -roll);
        _rigidbody.rotation *= AddRot;
        Vector3 AddPos = Vector3.forward;
        AddPos = _rigidbody.rotation * AddPos;
        if (isGrounded == true) {
            landingSpeed = Input.GetAxis ("LandingSpeed") * (Time.deltaTime * AmbientSpeed);
            _rigidbody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.deltaTime * AmbientSpeed + landingSpeed);
            if (landingSpeed == 100)
                landingSpeed = 0.0f;
            displaylandingspeed.text = landingSpeed.ToString ();
        }
    }
}
```

I added the variable displaylandingspeed but it's not showing it at all when running the game.

Two screenshots the first showing the Text Inspector.
The second showing the GameObject with the script and the Text attached to it.

[image: Text1]

[image: Text2]

Comment: trying setting some text in the `Start` to see where the problem is

Comment: Is the object grounded?

Comment: I used a break point now on the line: displaylandingspeed.text = landingSpeed.ToString (); when it stopped there i clicked to continue then it throw exception say displaylandingspeed is null.

Comment: Now i tried in the Start function to make for a test: displaylandingspeed = "hello"; and when building the script i got error on this line say: Cannont implicity convert type 'string' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Comment: Do **not** do `displaylandingspeed = "My Text";`. This should be  `displaylandingspeed.text = "My Text";`

Comment: Have you assigned your text object to the variable in your script, in the unity inspector?

Comment: @AnmolMahatpurkar yes now i added a GameObject > UI > Text under the object with the script. So now in the inspector i have the Text. And then i added the Text to the displaylandingspeed in the inspector. Now i'm not getting the null but still i don't see the text in the game window when running the game.

Comment: I added now to my question two screenshots one showing the Inspector of Text the second showing the object where the Text and the Script attached to. Still i don't see the text in real time when running the game.

Comment: And when using a break point now it's getting to the line displaylandingspeed.text = landingSpeed.ToString (); and when doing continue it keep stop on the line fine. First the text is "hello" then each time "0" so it's working but it's displaying it on the game display and/or the scene display when running the game.

Comment: your text object should always be added under canvas. If none of parent object doesn't have canvas attached, it would be visible. And there are few other things to try. increase font size up to 50. change inspector from debug mode to normal inspector and set anchor to middle center by holding Alt + Shift keys.

Comment: The problem was that the Text it self the Text object was not in the position of the terrain and the objects. I had to change it's local position to see it. So it's not showing displaying it on the game screen/display it's showing in the game scene world. I thought it will show it on the game display. Anyway now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text object that can be seen in the screenshot is not a child of a Canvas. Any object with the Unity UI components should be a child of a Canvas Object. Only then will it be rendered on the screen.

Make your text object a child of the Canvas object, and the problem should be solved.